# How to update GeoFire library to the latest version?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I'm developing an android app and I'm using `GeoFire` library in it.

I have updated all of my code as per the latest version of `Firebase`, but I failed in updating `GeoFire` to the latest version which is causing a code conflict.

Even on the github website of [geofire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java), there is no such information.

Upon running the app with old geofire version, I'm getting this error: `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: You need to set the Android context using Firebase.setAndroidContext() before using Firebase.` on this line `geoFire = new GeoFire(new Firebase("https://appname.firebaseio.com/appDetails/"));`

And upon adding `Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);` again, I'm getting this error: `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Android classes not found. Are you using the firebase-client-android artifact?`

How to update to the latest version of `GeoFire`?

Please let me know.

Comment: The  compatible GeoFire version is not yet ready, you'll need to wait...

Comment: @Ymmanuel WHOA! are you sure? till when I have to wait? I am already very late. I have to submit my app before June 24th for AdMob student app challenge.

Comment: In the issues of the goofier version they gave an estimate of weeks  15 days ago....  here is the link https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc/issues/37

Comment: So what should I do now? Should I downgrade all of my updated code?

Comment: If your project is not so complex you can use GeoHashes and copy from the geofire library the rules to make the search precision...and create your custom functionality...is  not that complex

Comment: Since you have a small timeframe it would be better to downgrade

Comment: I have got something here: https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java/pull/20 Can you help me figure out what's happening therE? I got this link from here: https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java/issues/18

Comment: Since Geofire is open source, some guys have pushed their versions of the migration, but the versions have not been fully tested to be released as a reliable version...It could be ready by next week or it could take three more weeks....

Comment: it depends on the validation so there is no real date yet...

Comment: can I also update that `GeoFire.java` file of my project?

Comment: Yes you can try to use it, even if it is not fully validated maybe the functionality you need will be there

Comment: I am unable to edit that file!

Comment: you can create a pull request for that version and download it from github

Answer (score 0):

Same here! Watch out for the new update. 
Check out this [OPEN Issues](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java/issues/18) on Github. Once resolve, we'll be able to get the latest library.

Hoping this will be done as soon as possible. 
JavaScript has been updated already. Android / iOS still on process.